# How can I reduce the number of variables on the bubble sorting?

Tags: python, arrays, sorting, bubble-sort

I made a bubble sort code. It works fine but I want to reduce the number of variables. I would like to use only `i` in the code. How can I remove `j`?

```
def bubble(v):
    l = len(v)
    for i in range(l-1):
        for j in range(l-i-1):
            if v[j]>v[j+1]:
                v[j+1],v[j] = v[j],v[j+1]
        return v
```

Comment: If you have two nested loops you need two separate loop variables. You can't remove `j` and use only `i`.

Comment: Or are you asking how to write a sorting algorithm which does not have two nested loops? I guess that wouldn't be bubble sort anymore.

Comment: *"It works fine"*: Your code does not work. `return` occurs in the first iteration of the outer loop.

Answer (score 0):

One of the possible ways is to use a list of length two, one for storing `i` and the other for storing `j`, in this fashion:

```
def bubble(v):
    l = len(v)
    i = [0, 0]                                     # use like [i, j]
    while i[0] < (l-1):
        i[1] = 0
        while i[1] < (l-i[0]-1):
            if v[i[1]]>v[i[1]+1]:
                v[i[1]+1],v[i[1]] = v[i[1]],v[i[1]+1]
            i[1] += 1
        return v
        i[0] += 1
```

Note that, here, we have to use `while` loops instead of `for` loops.